# How to allow for redirect url in bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am brand new to bootstrap and I have come to a problem.

I want to be able to redirect the user from the navbar to either sign in or log in to the website.  However, when I have following html, the browser recognize the correct url redirect. but when you click on it, no action happens.  If I put the  statement outside of the navbar, it redirect fine.  Am I missing some setting for navbar? Thanks for any help you can give.

```
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">SIGN UP</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">LOG IN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I also have this script for the navbar.  Not sure if this makes any difference.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
    $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 900, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;

    });
  });
```

Comment: can you show me problem working link?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud. When you press Sign In or Log On, nothing happens.  I'm not sure how to debug this. The link in questions is 'registration_register' and 'auth_login'.

Comment: Where you want to link sign Up and Log in ? tell me the right location.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud. This is implemented within Django. The link would be .../accounts/register/ and .../accounts/login/. Is that what you are asking? I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for. The <a href> statements when I move them out of the nav bar. so I think those work.

Comment: This isnt a bootstrap problem, if you replace the hrefs with www.google.com it will work fine. This is a problem with you django. jsfiddle.net/5pfot40u/

Comment: @Daniel Kobe.  I see.  Thanks I will change this to a Django questions.

Comment: You can also open up the developer console and check what exactly is being placed in the hrefs

Comment: @DanielKobe What would you use for this cross python/javascript problem?

Comment: I've never worked with Django before. But chrome developer console is a really powerful tool. You said that it works outside of the navbar, that sounds really strange to me. What I would do is put the link in the navbar and outside of the navbar. Then use inspect element in chrome (right click --> inspect) and check to see what the difference between the two hrefs are. Because the hrefs are being generated dynamically you cant know what they are until the page is loaded.

Comment: @DanielKobe. Thanks.  I discovered the problem.  It seems like the hash is not set. If you include, the script language I added. Changing the <a href> to google.com also doesn't work.  I think it is a query issue where the hash is not set.  Have you seen this before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97468/discussion-between-daniel-kobe-and-h-c).

Comment: Hey try this! http://jsfiddle.net/5pfot40u/ Looks like its working